# How can you disable line numbers in git grep when you have grep.lineNumber=true?

Tags: bash, git, grep

I have `grep.lineNumber=true` in my ~/.gitconfig because I almost always want to show them. Sometimes though, I want to disable them for a single command without editing the config file. Is there an option I can pass to git grep that disables line numbers? There are of course a few ways around it (see below), but I'm curious to know if there is a built-in solution.

Some ways I've found to work around it:

1. Pipe through another tool that removes the line numbers (depending on the situation e.g. `cut`, `awk`, `sed`, `grep`, etc)
2. Use normal `grep` (or any of its variants like `egrep`), where I happen to not have this turned on by default

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
git -c grep.lineNumber=false grep…
```

See [the docs for `git -c`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git#Documentation/git.txt--cltnamegtltvaluegt).